# Subtract constant value from each element in an array bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I am working on processing an array of values that I want to offset by a constant value of 800. Is there a simple way to go about doing this in bash?

Comment: why you use shell scripts for this? why not python/ruby/js?

Comment: Purely due to other constraints. It is incorporated into a script that boots a bunch of other processes that can only be launched in bash.

Comment: `for i in "${!a[@]}"; do ((b[i]=${a[i]} - 800)); done` or assign back to `a` to re-use the same array.

Answer (score 1):

just iterate through:

```
len=${#ar[*]}
for (( i=0; i<=$(( $len -1 )); i++ ))
do
    ar[$i]=$((${ar[$i]} - 800))
done
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without a loop? if no, why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ xx=( 11 22 33 )


$ for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#xx[@]} ; i++ )) do  (( xx[$i]=${xx[$i]} + 800 )) ; done


$ echo ${xx[@]}
811 822 833
```

Comment: @RobEven whatever operations bash supports, the bit to the right of the = is just an arbitrary expression, but I'd have to check exactly what bash does support these days, I almost never need to bash arithmetic :-)

Comment: Same, that is why I posted here. I mostly use java and c++ which are much more intuitive.

Comment: The code can be written in a way that might be much more familiar to a C++ programmer:  
`declare -i -a xx=( 11 22 33 ) ; declare -i i=${#xx[*]} ; while (( i )) ; do xx[--i]+=800 ; done`